# How to get request duration from sleuth tracer

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I have my setup with sleuth (spring-cloud-starter-sleuth) and zipkin (spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin) which works perfectly fine. At the same time I would like to log to ELK duration of the requests. I was trying to get this information from currentSpan like

```
tracer.currentSpan().context()
```

but I don't see anything related to duration or start time. Any ideas how I can get duration or when current span (request) was started?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from the span not the context. If you're using brave you can register your own SpanHandler beam that handles finished spans. There you have access to a MutableSpan that can give you the duration